# How to set and get data from an odontogram in react js?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, state, use-reducer

I am trying to get and set data from an odontogram(this one to be exact https://codesandbox.io/s/myy7z75z9j ), the odontogram works but i can't get the data and set it... I was trying to use an "state" to storage but the problem was that the state reset every time I change of tooth (and I need all the changes to be stored in a single object array)... the second problem was to set the data... for example i need to set:
`0: {place: "left", num: 38, type: "carie", value: 1} 1: {place: "left", num: 38, type: "carie", value: 1}`

I tried to set it using useEffect like this:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
//getting data from localstorage
     const r = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('procedure'))
    if(r){                
     console.log(r[0].lugar)
     dispatch(carie(r[0].lugar, r[0].valor));
    return
    }
},[])
```

But the problem was that every single tooth was marked.
Any Idea tha how can I set and get this data ?

Odontogram:

```
    import React from 'react';
import './Odontogram.css';
import Teeth from './Teeth';

function Odontogram() {

  let odontogramState = {};

  const handleToothUpdate = (id, toothState) => {
    odontogramState[id] = toothState;
    console.log("changeee")
  };
 
  return (

    <div className="Odontogram">
      <svg version="1.1" height="100%" width="100%" >
        <Teeth start={18} end={11} x={0} y={0} handleChange={handleToothUpdate} />
        <Teeth start={21} end={28} x={210} y={0} handleChange={handleToothUpdate} />

        <Teeth start={55} end={51} x={75} y={40} handleChange={handleToothUpdate} />
        <Teeth start={61} end={65} x={210} y={40} handleChange={handleToothUpdate} />

        <Teeth start={85} end={81} x={75} y={80} handleChange={handleToothUpdate} />
        <Teeth start={71} end={75} x={210} y={80} handleChange={handleToothUpdate} />

        <Teeth start={48} end={41} x={0} y={120} handleChange={handleToothUpdate} />
        <Teeth start={31} end={38} x={210} y={120} handleChange={handleToothUpdate} />
      </svg>
    {/* <button onClick={()=> alert("you clicked")}> guardar</button> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

export default Odontogram;

Teeth:

```
  import React from 'react';
import Tooth from './Tooth';

function Teeth({ start, end, x, y, handleChange }) {
    let tooths = getArray(start, end);
   
    return (
       
        <g transform="scale(1.4)" id="gmain">
       
            {
                tooths.map((i) =>
                    <Tooth onChange={handleChange}
                        key={i}
                        number={i}
                        positionY={y}
                        positionX={Math.abs((i - start) * 25) + x}
                    />
                )
            }
        </g>
    )
}

function getArray(start, end) {
    if (start > end) return getInverseArray(start, end);

    let list = [];
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        list.push(i);
    }

    return list;
}

function getInverseArray(start, end) {
    let list = [];

    for (var i = start; i >= end; i--) {
        list.push(i);
    }

    return list;
}

export default Teeth;
```

Tooth:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useReducer, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import useContextMenu from 'contextmenu';
import 'contextmenu/ContextMenu.css';
import './Tooth.css';


function Tooth({ number, positionX, positionY, onChange }) {
   
    
    
    const [data, setData] = useState([]) //ADDED FOR ME TO STORAGE THE DATA
    
    const initialState = {
        Cavities: {
            center: 0,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0
        },
        Extract: 0,
        Crown: 0,
        Filter: 0,
        Fracture: 0
    };

    function reducer(toothState, action) {
     
        //I added this setData but reset every time I change of tooth
            setData((prevItems) => {
                const newItems = [...prevItems, {place: action.zone, num: number, type: action.type, value: action.value}];
                window.localStorage.setItem("procedure", JSON.stringify(newItems));
                // datos.current.concat({newItems})
                return newItems;
              });
   

        switch (action.type) {
            case 'crown':
                return { ...toothState, Crown: action.value };
            case 'extract':
                return { ...toothState, Extract: action.value };
            case 'filter':
                return { ...toothState, Filter: action.value };
            case 'fracture':
                return { ...toothState, Fracture: action.value };
            case 'carie':
                return { ...toothState, Cavities: setCavities(toothState, action.zone, action.value) };
            case 'clear':
                return initialState;
            default:
                throw new Error();
        }


    }

    const crown = (val) => ({ type: "crown", value: val });
    const extract = (val) => ({ type: "extract", value: val });
    const filter = (val) => ({ type: "filter", value: val });
    const fracture = (val) => ({ type: "fracture", value: val });
    const carie = (z, val) => ({ type: "carie", value: val, zone: z });
    const clear = () => ({ type: "clear" });

    const [toothState, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const [contextMenu, useCM] = useContextMenu({ submenuSymbol: '>' });

    const firstUpdate = useRef(true);
    useEffect(() => { 
        if (firstUpdate.current) {
            firstUpdate.current = false;
            return;
        }

        onChange(number, toothState);
   

    }, [toothState, onChange, number]);

    
    // Done SubMenu
    const doneSubMenu = (place, value) => {
        return {
            'Cavity': () => {
                dispatch(carie(place, value))   
            },
            'Cavities All': () => dispatch(carie('all', value)),
            'Absent': () => dispatch(extract(value)),
            'Crown': () => dispatch(crown(value)),
        }
    }

    // Todo SubMenu
    const todoSubMenu = (place, value) => {
        return {
            'Cavity': () => dispatch(carie(place, value)),
            'Cavities All': () => dispatch(carie('all', value)),
            'Absent': () => dispatch(extract(value)),
            'Crown': () => dispatch(crown(value)),
            'Filtered Out': () => dispatch(filter(value)),
            'Fractured': () => dispatch(fracture(value)),
        }
    }

    // Main ContextMenu
    const menuConfig = (place) => {
        return {
            'Done': doneSubMenu(place, 1),
            'To Do': todoSubMenu(place, 2),
            'JSX line': <hr></hr>,
            'Clear All': () => dispatch(clear()),
        }
    };

    let getClassNamesByZone = (zone) => {
        if (toothState.Cavities) {
            if (toothState.Cavities[zone] === 1) {
                return 'to-do';
            } else if (toothState.Cavities[zone] === 2) {
                return 'done';
            }
        }

        return '';
    }

    // Tooth position
    const translate = `translate(${positionX},${positionY})`;

    //ADDED FOR ME
    // useEffect(()=>{
    // //getting data from localstorage
    //      const r = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('procedure'))
    //     if(r){                
    //      console.log(r[0].lugar)
    //      dispatch(carie(r[0].lugar, r[0].valor));
    //     return
    //     }
    // },[])
   
    // console.log(toothState)
    return (

        <svg className="tooth">
            <g transform={translate}>
                <polygon
                    points="0,0 20,0 15,5 5,5"
                    onContextMenu={useCM(menuConfig('top'))}
                    className={getClassNamesByZone('top')}
                    onClick={useCM(menuConfig('top'))}
                />
                <polygon
                    points="5,15 15,15 20,20 0,20"
                    onContextMenu={useCM(menuConfig('bottom'))}
                    className={getClassNamesByZone('bottom')}
                />
                <polygon
                    points="15,5 20,0 20,20 15,15"
                    onContextMenu={useCM(menuConfig('left'))}
                    className={getClassNamesByZone('left')}
                />
                <polygon
                    points="0,0 5,5 5,15 0,20"
                    onContextMenu={useCM(menuConfig('right'))}
                    className={getClassNamesByZone('right')}
                />
                <polygon
                    points="5,5 15,5 15,15 5,15"
                    onContextMenu={useCM(menuConfig('center'))}
                    className={getClassNamesByZone('center')}
                />
                {drawToothActions()}
                <text
                    x="6"
                    y="30"
                    stroke="navy"
                    fill="navy"
                    strokeWidth="0.1"
                    className="tooth">
                    {number}
                </text>
            </g>
            {contextMenu}
           
        </svg>

    )

    function setCavities(prevState, zone, value) {
        if (prevState && prevState.Cavities) {
            if (zone === "all") {
                prevState.Cavities =
                {
                    center: value,
                    top: value,
                    bottom: value,
                    left: value,
                    right: value
                }
            } else {
                prevState.Cavities[zone] = value;
            }

            return prevState.Cavities;
        }
    }

    function drawToothActions() {
        let otherFigures = null;
        if (toothState.Extract > 0) {
            otherFigures = <g stroke={toothState.Extract === 1 ? "red" : "blue"}>
                <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="20" y2="20" strokeWidth="2" />
                <line x1="0" y1="20" x2="20" y2="0" strokeWidth="2" />
            </g>
        }

        if (toothState.Fracture > 0) {
            otherFigures = <g stroke={toothState.Fracture === 1 ? "red" : "blue"}>
                <line x1="0" y1="10" x2="20" y2="10" strokeWidth="2"></line>
            </g>
        }

        if (toothState.Filter > 0) {
            otherFigures = <g stroke={toothState.Fracture === 1 ? "red" : "blue"}>
                <line x1="0" y1="20" x2="20" y2="0" strokeWidth="2" />
            </g>
        }

        if (toothState.Crown > 0) {
            otherFigures = <circle
                cx="10"
                cy="10"
                r="10"
                fill="none"
                stroke={toothState.Crown === 1 ? "red" : "blue"}
                strokeWidth="2"
            />;
        }

        return otherFigures;
    }
}

export default Tooth;
```